# Regex for specific pattern ending with )

Tags: java, regex

I have a big string, for example: "s#$_123 /HEC2w.,-&#--**HALOENCRYPT(177ey7y37, 'zimba')**,dnjekkq%12nnv**HALOENCRYPT(ECRa12 _*,'grate')**,eqn12&*;". I am looking to extract all the substrings with pattern "HALOENCRYPT(<Any_char_or_symbol_sequence>)" which means starting with **'HALOENCRYPT('** and ending immediately with **')'** with any sequence between them. which has been marked Bold in the input sequence. I want to extract all such substrings and add to a list.

This is the program i wrote which works partially:

```
String s = "s#$_123 /HEC2w.,-&#--HALOENCRYPT(177ey7y37,     'zimba'),dnjekkq%12nnvHALOENCRYPT(ECRa12 _*,'grate'),eqn12&*;";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("HALOENCRYPT[0-9a-zA-Z(,_ ')/-]+").matcher(s);
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find()) {
    myList.add(m.group())
}
```

The above string is giving out extra characters after HALOENCRYPT(177ey7y37, 'zimba') and HALOENCRYPT(ECRa12 _*,'grate')

What i am expecting in the list is:
HALOENCRYPT(177ey7y37, 'zimba') and HALOENCRYPT(ECRa12 _*,'grate')

What i could not figure out is how to provide regex for **ANYTHING** between **(** and **)**

Comment: `.` matches everything in most regex versions

Comment: Like `HALOENCRYPT\([^()]*\)` https://regex101.com/r/lLf9aT/1

Comment: Can the text between `(` and `)` include `(` or `)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *reluctant* quantifier:

```
HALOENCRYPT\(.*?\)
```

And use the `results()` method to stream and collect the matches:

```
List<String> myList = Pattern.compile("HALOENCRYPT\\(.+?\\)").matcher(s).results()
  .map(MatchResult::group)
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
HALOENCRYPT[0-9a-zA-Z(,_ ')/-]+
```

just do:

```
HALOENCRYPT\([0-9a-zA-Z,_ '/-]+\)
```

Comment: I am looking for pattern for ANYTHING between ( and ). I don't want to give specific pattern like 0-9a-zA-Z,_ ... because there could be anything between ( and ), not just the characters provided above.

Comment: So it will be as @The fourth bird suggested: `HALOENCRYPT\([^()]+\)`

Comment: Answer looks good. Does it work for line breaks too, for example of there is line break after HALO, like "HALO" + "\n" + ENCRYPT(blah-blah) ?